# Vue CLI 4.5.*: "export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-cli-4

While working with Vue CLI 4.5.x, I tried the following code:

```
import Vue from "vue"
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    render: h=> h(App)
})
```

But unfortunately, it gave the following warnings:

> `"export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'`

What I can conclude from this, is that Vue CLI 4.5.x has stopped this way of creating an application where you first create a Vue instance.

To initialize the main application, the official way is as follows:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

I'm not sure if my conclusion is correct or not. It would be a great help if somebody would concrete my conclusion, as so far I have not found any proof of that in official documentation of vue.

Moreover, the later code comes baked with Vue CLI 4.5.* application instance, while former code is true when using the CDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've installed vue 3 using vue-cli 4 and this version has this [new global api](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#a-new-global-api-createapp) for creating new app :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

const app = createApp({})
```

You're still able to create apps using vue 2 based on vue cli 4 but you should indicate the version when you launch new project.

Comment: Yeah I saw the option of Vue2 but I thought I should better start with vue 3, you know like sort of ready for the future. But thanks Boussadjra.. you are a great help.

Comment: @GursewakSingh it's not the time to start with vue 3 if you're new in vue, you should focus on vue 2 because there's a lot of resources on internet that could help you learning vue 2, vue 3 is released officially since the last Friday

Comment: Thanks, but I am not new to Vue its just like coming to vue after 4 or 5 months.

Comment: Since we cannot create a Vue instance in vue 3 therefore we cannot create a event bus.. if am not wrong....?

Comment: You're right but there's a solution please check my answer [here] for more details, don't forget to give a point if it is helpful